# set width on jquery selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, styles

I'm working on a small project and having difficulty getting selectmenu and its items to stretch to fill a container. A width is being set and I can't really tell where. I am new to this plugin and not much of a web dev.

It looks like the styles are defined in the stylesheet:

```
#PDropdown .ui-widget, .ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-widget{ 
font-family:'Lucida Sans';
font-size:.85em;
width: 97%; /* gets overridden....*/
```

}

However when the page is rendered, a width is applied:

```
<a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-dropdown" id="PDropDownList-button" role="button" href="#nogo" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="PDropDownList-menu" style="width: 135px;" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Item</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
```

How can I set this to be 100% width? Sorry if this is simple.

Comment: The style is being defined in jQueryUI SelectMenu > `width: this.element.outerWidth()` - It's grabbing the current outer width and applying it as a specific pixel width.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The outer container is a div that doesn't have a width and stretches horizontally to the next element, so where does that width come from?

Comment: I was just providing some insight on what it was doing, go with the use of !important to attempt to resolve. To clarify more, it captures the element's current outerWidth or total width in pixels. It doesn't use the containers width. This can be bad if on a responsive site because that width could stretch with the window but the plugin just grabbed the width at the time of initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I talked to the dev who modified the control originally, and they can change it back. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's not a very good practice, but for the sake of simplicity you can add `!important` to the CSS rule, it will protect it from overriding. Like this:

```
width: 97% !important;
```

Also you may need to add this rule;

```
.ui-selectmenu-open {width: 97.3% !important;}
```

Works on this page http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html

Again, keep in ming, that it's a really bad hack and I'm suggesting it only because you said you're not a web dev and it's the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works but the items do not stretch to that width. It only stretches the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Marked as an answer since it does work, even if it's a hack. Sometimes a hack is ok. :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to declare width of the selectmenu in percentage but jQuery reduces it by 2% every time. I don't know why.

This examle creates selectmenu with width 98%. This selecmenu is responsive.

```
$("select").selecmenu(
    {
        width: "100%"
    }
);
```

I avoided this behavior with using "calc" function.

```
$("select").selecmenu(
    {
        width: "calc(100% - 1px)"
    }
);
```

1px reduction is there because the width of the selectmenu is widen by jQuery to avoid wrapping.
I used this solution for jQuery UI version 1.11.4

Comment: This is the only method that helped me. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it dynamically (responsive, and with percentages):

Declare the percentage in your CSS:

```
 select{
    width: 100%;
 }
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
jQuery("select").selectmenu(
        {
            width:  jQuery(this).attr("width"),
        }   
);
```